# Postgres pg_dump show empty file

Tags: php, postgresql, pg-dump

I am using this command in wamp, but I am getting empty `Mybackup.sql` file, did my knows what I am missing?

```
<?php    exec("pg_dump -U postgres taro-api > Mybackup.sql"); ?>
```

Comment: How do you authenticate to postgres server? Are you running this code as an unix user, who has the privilege to connect to postgres server as an user postgres?

Comment: I am executing this through wamp in window machine, please note I am running pg_queries with ease.

Comment: You command probably causes an error, that's why nothing is written.

Comment: @Laurenz this is what I am trying to trace.

Comment: Append `2>&1` to the command, then the error message will be added to the output. That should help. Perhaps `pg_dump` is not on the `PATH`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe after adding 2>&1, I got this message "operable program or batch file."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the additional information from the comments, it becomes clear that you are on Windows and `pg_dump` is not on your `PATH`.

Either use the full absolute path for `pg_dump` or add the directory to the `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: you are helping me alot, can you give me favor that how can I set this? pg_dump is located here, C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\bin, but I want whenever I go live I don't face same issue.

Comment: Then use `\"C:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\10\\bin\\pg_dump\" -U postgres -d taro-api -f Mybackup.sql`.

Comment: print_r(exec('\"C:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\10\\bin\\pg_dump\" -U postgres -d taro-api -f 2>&1 Mybackup.sql')); response message "operable program or batch file." this empty .sql is not created as well

Comment: If you use single quotesnfor the `exec` argument, do away with the backslashes escaping the double quotes.

Comment: thank you for advice, it keep executing and never ending, in fact wamp is crashed

Comment: is there any other way to take backup?

Comment: This is the only way to make a logical backup. By the way, you messed up the command. It should be `exec('"C:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\10\\bin\\pg_dump" -U postgres -d taro-api -f Mybackup.sql 2>&1')`.

Comment: thankyou for your time and help, but above line still crashed the wamp

Comment: If you define "crash", maybe somebody else can help you. I don't know enough about PHP.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186840/discussion-between-kamran-sohail-and-laurenz-albe).